# How to convert centimeter value into feet using multi-slider in react-native?

Tags: react-native

When I used multi-slider I faced one issue is that when I scroll slider I got only `centimeter` value I did not change feet value so I need help to change `centimeter` value with change feet value.

```
 class App extends React.Component {
        state = {
            sliderOneChanging: false,
            sliderOneValue: [5],
            multiSliderValue: [122, 222],
        };

        multiSliderValuesChange = values => {
            this.setState({
                multiSliderValue: values,
            });
        };
    render() {
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <View style={styles.sliders}>
                        <View style={styles.sliderOne}>
                            <Text style={styles.text}>{this.state.multiSliderValue[0]} cm </Text>
                            <Text style={styles.text}>({this.state.multiSliderValue[0]})</Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.containerSlider}>
                    <MultiSlider
                    values={[
                      this.state.multiSliderValue[0],
                     ]}
                     sliderLength={400}
                            onValuesChange={this.multiSliderValuesChange}
                            min={122}
                            max={222}
                            allowOverlap
                            snapped
                        selectedStyle={{
                            backgroundColor: 'pink',
                        }}
                        unselectedStyle={{
                            backgroundColor: 'silver', 
                        }}
                        trackStyle={{
                            height: 2,
                        }}
                    />
                    </View>
                </View>
            );
        }
    }
```

[image: user-interface like this]

Comment: please explain more we did not get your point

Comment: what you  want ?

Comment: I want centimeter value convert to feet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can create one function which return feet value like

```
 const convertedCentoFeet = (values) => {
  var realFeet = ((values * 0.393700) / 12);
  var feet = Math.floor(realFeet);
  var inches = Math.round((realFeet - feet) * 12);
  return feet+"'"+inches;
}
```

then use it like

```
 <Text style={styles.text}>({convertedCentoFeet(this.state.multiSliderValue[0])}"))</Text>
```